# PHP and JavaScript post parameters error

Tags: javascript, php, post

I am trying to use PHP and JavaScript to pass some parameters using the `$_POST` method, in a signup page.

However, all I get is: `The email <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> is about to be registered (account ref = <?php echo $_POST['accountref']; ?>`, basically the code.

Am I doing something wrong (with the `$_POST` method)?

---

scripts/signup.js

```
var accountref = "myaccountref";
window.location.href = 'signup.php?email=' + document.getElementById("signup_email").value + '&user=' + document.getElementById("signup_user").value + '&pass=' + document.getElementById("signup_pass") + '&accountref=' + accountref;
```

---

signup.php

```
<?php
$email;
$user;
$pass;
$accountref;
?>

<script type = "text/javascript">
alert("The email <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> is about to be registered (account ref = <?php echo $_POST['accountref']; ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: Problem number 1. Those values are being sent as `GET`, not `POST`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be passing sensitive data like passwords via query string.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - I tried the code `<script>
var email = <?php echo $_GET['email'] ?>;
alert(email);
</script> `, but no alert box appeared.

Comment: Somehow your PHP code is not being executed in signup.php file, whereas it should work like that. Remove any other PHP code there and try again, might be causing an error

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - Apart from some HTML code, that's all that I've got, and it "Worked" before I changed it to $_GET (although it didn't really work, [as noted in question]).

Comment: Remove `<?php
$email;
$user;
$pass;
$accountref;
?>
`

Comment: Check the .htaccess file or your server configurations to make sure that your .php files is being executed correctly.

Comment: @TrungDQ - I'm on a local server (my PC only) at the moment